# iOS: Make image width slightly smaller than screen width

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having an issue where my image is too big. I need it to be slightly less than what the screen width is.

Here's my controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageName = @"goldencoaster";

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table"]]];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.imageName]];
    CGRect bounds;
    bounds.origin = CGPointZero;
    bounds.size = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    self.coasterImage.bounds = bounds;
    self.coasterImage.image = image;
}
```

However, this returns this when I run the simulator:

[image]

How would I get the image to show up slightly smaller than the screen width?

====================================================================
**UPDATE**

So I took out auto layout as suggested, and updated my controller to look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageName = @"goldencoaster";

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table"]]];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.imageName]];

    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    CGRect bounds;
    bounds.origin.x = screen.origin.x + 10;
    bounds.origin.y = screen.origin.y + 10;
    bounds.size.width = screen.size.width - 100;

    self.coasterImage.frame = bounds;
    self.coasterImage.image = image;
}
```

However, now my image doesn't show up at all?? Only the background (image with name "table") shows up, but not the goldencoaster.

Comment: have you got your problem solved?

Comment: not yet, going to update my question to show the code i just tried out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.imageName = @"goldencoaster";

[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table"]]];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.imageName]];
CGRect bounds;
bounds.origin = CGPointZero;
bounds.size = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

self.coasterImage.bounds = bounds;
self.coasterImage.image = image;
self.coasterImage.frame = CGRectMake(20, 0,   self.view.frame.size.width-40, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.coasterImage.center = self.coasterImage.superview.center;

}
```

**Swift 3.1**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageName = "goldencoaster"

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "table")!)

    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    var bounds = CGRect()
    bounds.origin = CGPoint.zero
    bounds.size = (UIScreen.main.bounds).size

    coasterImage.bounds = bounds
    coasterImage.image = image
    coasterImage.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(20), y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width - CGFloat(40), height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    coasterImage.center = (coasterImage.superview?.center)!
}
```

Comment: nice that worked. I tweaked it so that it uses `self.view.frame.size.width-40` as the last argument for `CGRectMake` since I want it to have even sides

Comment: This is the pre-Auto Layout way of sizing views.  This may break when your view no longer is as big as the screen.  (Think side-by-side apps on iPad, coming in iOS 9.)  Size classes are a more robust way to handle this.

Comment: I haven't learned size classes yet but i'll look into it. When I click on it it makes my storyboard look like an ipad so that's why i'm not using it. I think this app would only exist for iphone 6+ though

Answer (score 1):

Two words: Auto Layout

[You want your UI to adapt to different devices, and orientations.](https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/)

[Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and size classes are designed to handle those needs.

**Update:**

You're checking screen size and setting bounds.  That suggests you're trying to size the view instead of letting Auto Layout constrain it.  Auto Layout takes the place of setting frame or bounds.  You don't want to mix the two.

Comment: I am using auto layout though.

Comment: You need to scale the image to fit its view, not overflow it.  The imageView's `contentMode` is probably set to Center.

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't using autolayout, you will need to edit the image frame. For example if you want to reduce the size in 10 pixels:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.imageName = @"goldencoaster";

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table"]]];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.imageName]];
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(screen.origin.x+10,
                  screen.origin.y+10,
                  screen.size.width-20,
                  screen.size.height-20);

    self.coasterImage.center = self.coasterImage.superview.center;
    self.coasterImage.frame = bounds;
    self.coasterImage.image = image;
}
```

Comment: Frames and Auto Layout don't mix.  Don't set frame or bounds because Auto Layout handles setting them for you.

Comment: really? ok after disabling auto layout, my image doesn't show up anymore. i'll update my question with my code

Comment: Don't disable Auto Layout.  Get rid of the image.bounds code.

Comment: oo yeh i think that would be cleaner

Comment: but for some reason it doesn't look right when i use auto layout. if i comment out the image.bounds stuff and use auto layout, the image doesn't stretch to the sides.

Comment: if you look at my code, the last line sets the image

Comment: @Edmund sorry, I removed by mistake the last line... I think this will run ;)

Comment: yeh nice i just tried yours, it works. however i want it to be a square with equal widths so i tweaked yours to use `screen.size.width-20` for the last argument of CGRectMake, but now it doesn't show up in the center of the screen.

Comment: Adding `self.coasterImage.center = self.coasterImage.superview.center;` gets it to show up in the center. thanks!

Comment: Well! I have edited my answer with your last comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with  contentMode  like

```
self.coasterImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

here are the  different contentMode  check it from here

```
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill

UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit      // contents scaled to fit with fixed aspect. remainder is transparent


UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill     // contents scaled to fill with fixed aspect. some portion of content may be clipped.

UIViewContentModeRedraw              // redraw on bounds change (calls -setNeedsDisplay)

UIViewContentModeCenter              // contents remain same size.    positioned adjusted.

UIViewContentModeTop

UIViewContentModeBottom

UIViewContentModeLeft

UIViewContentModeRight

UIViewContentModeTopLeft

UIViewContentModeTopRight

UIViewContentModeBottomLeft

UIViewContentModeBottomRight
```